# How to call a function inside another function in python

Tags: python

```
def print_money(n1, n2):
    print('hello world')
    money_sum = adds_numbers(n1, n2)
    print(money_sum)
def adds_numbers(n1,n2):
    print_money(n1,n2)

adds_numbers(2,3)
```

I am trying to call a function from another function, why is the result giving an infinite loop.

Comment: `adds_numbers()` calls `print_money()` and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

Because your `print_money` function is calling yet another `adds_number` function, which in turns call yet another `print_money` function, and will keep on repeating this loop forever.

Sidenote: I think what you want to do is

```
def adds_numbers(n1, n2):
    return n1 + n2 // Returns the sum of both numbers, as implied by the function name
```

Comment: An additional note: You can call print_money where you need the functionality, and the function will call on the adds_numbers for the addition

Answer (score -2):

Change add_numbers to return n1+n2, that fixes the code.

```
def print_money(n1, n2):
    print('hello world')
    money_sum = adds_numbers(n1, n2)
    print(money_sum)
def adds_numbers(n1,n2):
    return n1+n2

adds_numbers(2,3)
```